# jquery ui hangs on document click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a html page with over 1500 element  !!! 
and a menu .

when I click somewhere on document , the page locked for over 2 seconds (at least). 
After some search I found this block of code in JQuery.UI :

```
// Clicks outside of a menu collapse any open menus
    this._on( this.document, {
        click: function( event ) {
            if ( !$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu" ).length ) {
                this.collapseAll( event );
            }

            // Reset the mouseHandled flag
            this.mouseHandled = false;
        }
    });
```

the if statement fires over and over and it become problem .

How this could fix ?!

Comment: What have you tried. What errors are you getting? Help others reproduce the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The comments say what the function does - it closes any open jqueryui menus that've gone out of focus. You could try extending the widget to prevent this behaviour, or replace it with something custom-tailored to your page. ref. http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/

Comment: @blgt , I see the link you mention , but I can not find very useful . 
I already extend show method of jquery to remove hidden class . But i don't know how to override that function and change the behavior !